# mysql tempo médio, top 10 modelos

Tags: php, mysql

Pessoal conforme ilustração da minha tabela abaixo, eu gostaria de obter os seguintes dados:

✓ Tempo em que o POSTO gastou da DATA_ENTRADA ate a DATA_SAÍDA

✓ Tempo médio geral que todos os POSTOS levam da DATA_ENTRADA ate a DATA_SAÍDA

```
TABELA: OS  
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID | POSTO     | MODELO | DATA_ENTRADA | DATA_SAIDA          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | SÃO PAULO | FW100  | 2014-11-17   | 2014-11-19 12:59:00 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Testa e vê se funciona corretamente.

Comment: sim @JorgeB. testei e aparentemente funciona

Comment: @Hugo Qual a dúvida que resta então?

Comment: Ou seja, porque duvida que sua lógica esteja incorreta? Se a única dúvida é sobre o `TOP 10` (item 3), porque citar `POSTO` e `POSTOS` (item 1 e 2)?

Comment: @Thomas editei o posto, veja se consegue me compreender

Comment: @brasofilo melhor agora?

Comment: @Hugo Poderia colocar o nome da tabela na pergunta também? Para ajudar nos exemplos de quem for dar a resposta.

Comment: Ok, o que você gostaria parece claro, acho que falta agora dizer o que você tentou e quais problemas teve ao tentar implementar. Se não, fica parecendo que vc está pedindo que façam o trabalho pra você.

Comment: @Thomas feito ;)

Comment: Hugo da próxima vez, ou mesmo nesta (editando), tente demonstrar o que fez. Colocando em seguida a dúvida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tempo em que o POSTO gastou da DATA_ENTRADA ate a DATA_SAÍDA

Soma de minutos que tal POSTO gastou:

```
SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,DATA_ENTRADA,DATA_SAIDA)) AS tempo_total_posto FROM `OS` WHERE POSTO = 'SÃO PAULO'
```

> Tempo médio geral que todos os POSTOS levam da DATA_ENTRADA ate a DATA_SAÍDA

Tempo médio geral de minutos gastos

```
SELECT AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,DATA_ENTRADA,DATA_SAIDA)) AS media_geral FROM `OS`
```

Comment: 2 perguntas, as vezes a diferença da DATA_ENTRADA e DATA_SAIDA é de dias, daria pra converter os minutos em dias no php? Outra como fazer para que lista o resultado em todas as linhas não só especificando o posto

Comment: @Hugo 1) Daria, é só dividir: `$dias = ($minutos / 60) / 24;` ou então mudar o parâmetro da função `TIMESTAMPDIFF` de `MINUTE` para `DAY`. 2) É só remover o `WHERE POSTO`...  Outra coisa, recomendo que, se você for iniciante, não tenha medo de criar mais perguntas no S.O., mas que não fique usando essa pergunta para outras coisas além do enunciado original, pois prejudica a comunidade.

Comment: meu camarada obrigado pela dica